Is there a way to snap Bézier curve handles to axes or angles?
I want to have Bézier curve handles align at 0 or 90 degrees which is the same as aligning them to the X or Z axes in my case. Is there a way to do this in Blender?

select just the handles -> s y 0 -> align to x axis -> if there are multiple points selected, don't forget to set individual origins. use s x 0 to align to y axis.


